# thead border bottom, remove space between columns

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I just want a solid blue line underneath my table header, right now there are little white separations in between each column because the styling is on each `th`.

```
thead th {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #D3E6F5;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Here is my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eRQWc/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `cellspacing = "0"` html attribute or CSS property `border-spacing: 0` to your `table` element.

[**Example with cellspacing attribute**](http://jsfiddle.net/eRQWc/4/)

[**Example with border-spacing CSS property**](http://jsfiddle.net/eRQWc/8/)